# script that returns list of global variables containing specified string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, global-variables

taking a linux 101 course using bash shell and have an assignment to creaet a script that:

Lists all global variables that contain the string given in the command line argument. Do this using a pipe calling env and grep to filter the output of env for variables which contain the string given as an argument to the script.

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Lists all global variables that contain the string given in the command line argument. 

env | grep "something with metacharacater/wildcard? ???????
done
```

am I anywhere close? plz help this is the last question on an assignment & I just can't seem to wrap my head around it! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
env | grep "$1"
```

The first command line argument is called `$1`, the second is `$2` and so on.